# How to use zend_navigation to populate zend_feed?

Tags: zend-framework, rss, zend-navigation, zend-feed

In the bootstrap file of each of my modules I am populating my Zend_Navigation instance so that I can create html/xml sitemaps, side-bar navigation, admin navigation and, now, I want to create an rss feed.

Instead of duplicating code and adding the pages to Zend_Feed, is there a way to use Zend_Navigation to populate Zend_Feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended Zend_View_Helper_Navigation to take the nav, create an array ($feed) of items that Zend_Feed would accept, and returned `Zend_Feed::importBuilder(new Zend_Feed_Builder($feed), 'rss')->saveXML();`

Answer (score 0):

Feeds are linear entries and do not support nested structures like Navigation.

However, Navigation Containers implement SPL Iterator Interfaces, so you can easily iterate them via `foreach` to pass the pages as feed entries.

But I think the better approach would be to add new feed entries when you add your pages to navigation containers, the same way.

Comment: I'm not really interested in the navigation structure, I just want to pop all my pages from Navigation into an rss feed. Anticipating this answer, though, I extended Zend_View_Helper_Navigation (instead of Zend_Navigation because I was in a hurry and not looking at what I was doing) to take the nav, create an array of items that Zend_Feed would accept, and returned the array.